# how to derive to_string methods for data types using ppx

Tags: ocaml, ppx, ocaml-dune

How can I derive `to_string` methods for data types using ppx with [jbuilder](http://jbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

For instance, I'm trying to use [`@@deriving show`](https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving/blob/6b75b9e4804b253945ab61a76ed4af539d6caf90/README.md#plugin-show) to derive `show_*` methods for a data type.  I have a simple `main.ml` file that looks like this:

```
open Core

type foo = Bar | Baz
  [@@deriving show]

let () = printf "%s\n" (show_foo Bar)
```

I have a `jbuild` file in the same directory that looks like this:

```
(jbuild_version 1)

(executables
 ((names (main))
  (libraries (core ppx_deriving))
  (preprocess (pps (ppx_deriving.show)))))

(install
 ((section bin)
  (files ((main.exe as my_foo)))))
```

When I run `jbuilder build`, I get the following error:

```
File "main.ml", line 6, characters 24-32:
Error: Unbound value show_foo
```

It seems like `jbuilder` doesn't run the `ppx_deriving.show` preprocessor, and doesn't generate the `show_foo` function.

Is my use of `@@derive show` correct?  Do I need to add something to my `jbuild` file to get it to work correctly?  Does `ppx_deriving` have a problem working with `jbuilder`?  Should I be using a different ppx library?  Should I be using a different build system?  How do most OCamlers deal with these kind of build system problems?

---

*edit*: I am using OCaml version 4.04.2, jbuilder version 1.0+beta11, and ppx_deriving version 4.1.

Comment: When posting questions about `jbuilder`, it is necessary to include a `*.opam` file?  Does `jbuilder` look at this file to figure out how to build the executable?

Comment: I just tried updating `jbuilder` and `ppx_deriving` and now this appears to work.  My `jbuilder` version is [1.0+beta12](https://github.com/janestreet/jbuilder/blob/1c85e646bc732189739e31e697b5e60bbd2221ba/CHANGES.md#10beta12-18082017) and `ppx_deriving` is version [4.2](https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving/blob/7969277d1ec02517f441930e449d115d64a2a778/CHANGELOG.md#42).

Comment: Using the two above package versions, this code also works with OCaml version `4.05.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found in the comments, this requires particular handling in `ppx_deriving` which was only merged in version 4.2.

The underlying reason is that `jbuilder` uses `ppx_driver` to apply ppx rewriters and not the `-ppx` flag.